# Group documents by field value

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by

**NOTE** this is NOT a «how to get counts of distinct values» question.  I want the docs, not the counts.

Let's say I have this mapping:

```
country, color, height, weight
```

I have indexed these documents:

```
1. RU, red, 180, 90
2. BY, green, 170, 80
3. BY, blue, 180, 75
4. KZ, blue, 180, 95
5. KZ, red, 185, 100
6. KZ, red, 175, 80
7. KZ, red, 170, 80
```

I want to execute a query like `groupby(country, color, doc_limit=2)` which would return something like this:

```
{
  "RU": {
    "red": [
      (doc 1. RU, red, 180, 90)
    ],
  },
  "BY": {
    "green": [
      (doc 2)
    ],
    "blue": [
      (doc 3)
    ]
  },
  "KZ": {
    "blue": [
      (doc 4)
    ],
    "red": [
      (doc 5),
      (doc 6)
    ]
  }
}
```

with no more than 2 documents in each bucket.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That can be achieved with a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `country` field, combined with a `terms` sub-aggregation on the `color` field and then finally a [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to get 2 matching docs per bucket

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "countries": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "country"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "colors": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "color"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "docs": {
                     "top_hits": {
                        "size": 2
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you, it does exactly what was required!

Comment: @Val how would you change the query if you wanted ALL documents and not top 2?

Comment: @MadisonHaynie 1) you have to create one more sub group with 'term aggs' on field '_id'. Let call it DOC-Agg.     2) Then create another sub group inside DOC-Agg with 'top-hits'. Obviously size going to be 1 since parent aggs is with _id.